# G-d's Name in Fridge Magnets (Erasing)

Tags: halacha, shemos-sacred-names, writing-printing, appliances

If one were to arrange fridge magnets of letters to spell G-d's name, what are the halachic ramifications of rearranging them (erasing)?

If the magnets were small dots, rather than letters, but were arranged closely so that it still displayed G-d's name, what difference is there to the above?

The former can be likened to writing letters on small pieces of paper, before sticking them down together, and the latter can be likened to the atoms that make up normal handwriting, or a dot matrix printer.

(This question is similar in nature to e-ink.)

Comment: 930913, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for this interesting question! Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: no source, but my instinct is that one shouldn't intentionally spell or scramble G-d's name in magnets, but it's not an issue if either of those things happen.  And it would only matter for the Hebrew Yod-Hey and Vav-Hey, and (maybe) Elo-him, not "GOD".

Answer (score 5):

In general, with any question about writing and erasing Hashem's name it is useful to check the halachos of writing and erasing on Shabbos, because there is a lot of overlap.

R' Moshe paskens that playing Scrabble on Shabbos is neither writing nor erasing, unless you're actually sticking them in their place like some deluxe sets. In that case he says one should be machmir (although even that is not a clear-cut issur). Accordingly, simply arranging two magnets or dots together in a way that they are not stuck in place would not be an issue for the question of writing Hashem's name. The teshuva is here:
http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=916&pgnum=227

Dots of ink are of course, not comparable, because once used, the ink is stuck permanently in place.

Comment: Can you prove that the laws of writing on shabbat (which require Melechet Machshevet ~ creative intent) are parallel to those of Shem HaShem (which do not)?

Comment: Valid point. However, see Taz 340:2 who proves this halacha from the Gemara in Shabbos 104b, according to which it appears that it is not possible to call separating the two letters, erasing. It is possible that not everyone agrees to this proof, though his argument is compelling.

Comment: @DoubleAA Doesn't it sound like the considerations in question relate exclusively to the _ma'aseh_ and not to the _machashava_, thus having more to do with the definition of _k'siva_ than with intent? (This would be similar to how we learn out laws of writing a _get_ from writing anything on _shabas_ - e.g. _chak tochos_.)

Comment: That _t'shuva_ says (last paragraph) "ולכן לדינא תליא אם יש איזה חבור דקובען הגבאי שלא יזוזו ממקומן יש לאסור כהמג״א ואם אין שום חבור רק שהעמידן אות זה אצל זה לבד אין לאסור". Magnets sound like the former ("שלא יזוזו ממקומן") to me.

Comment: Anyway, @DovF, welcome to the site, and thanks for your answer. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site.

Comment: @msh210 Thanks. And I hear what you're saying; it could be R' Moshe would be machmir depending on how strong the magnets are.

Comment: 1) I agree with @msh210 . 2) I agree that there can be similarities, just we need to be careful with drawing too exact a comparison. Shem HaShem for instance might only be kadosh if there is kavana lekadesh and kavana for that makom, let alone issues of photocopies and kavana for permanence. We can debate if these apply here but they do show that conceptually there is a gap between Shabbat and Shem HaShem.

Comment: @WAF It could be that since fridge magnets are definitionaly transient then no real kedusha comes into play even if you tried to mekadesh it. (Note that levels of transience is a perfect example of something that can vary widely between shabbat and here.)

Comment: I davka chose magnets because sticking them down is like the travel scrabble. (Shemirath Shabbath Kehilchathah 16:23 on setting words being assur on shabbat) Considering that the magnets are "set" in place, the questions are, do the letters make a word, and do dots make a letter?